# Visual Studio 2019 doesn't include files after GIT Pull

Tags: git, visual-studio

After pulling down a project from GIT, I encountered an unusual behavior in Visual Studio 2019. All the projects associated with the solution loaded but none of the project files or folders were included. Clicking 'Show All Files' didn't resolve the issue. Shutting down and deleting the .vs folder didn't remedy the situation.

Answer (score 0):

The culprit turned out that the GIT repository contained white space characters. Performing a pull URL encoded the path to the repository and included characters such as %20, 'In place of white space'. Visual Studio 19 doesn't approve of these characters in the directory. By removing the characters and reloading the project, all expected project files were also loaded.